# Airflow SparkSubmitOperator failing because of java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi

Tags: python, apache-spark, airflow

I'm trying to use Airflow [SparkSubmitOperator](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/spark_submit_operator.py) to trigger `spark-examples.jar` on a local Spark standalone, but I keep getting exceptions. When I manually submitted same job on the terminal, it works:

```
spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --master spark://<HOSTNAME>:7077 \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --executor-memory 1G \
  --total-executor-cores 1 \
  /path/to/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.1.jar \
  1000
```

I guess there's something I'm not doing right on airflow but I've not been able to figure it out yet. Here is the stacktrace:

```
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Cannot execute: ['spark-submit', '--master', 'local', '--conf', 'master=spark://<HOSTNAME>:7077', '--num-executors', '1', '--total-executor-cores', '1', '--executor-cores', '1', '--executor-memory', '2g', '--driver-memory', '1g', '--name', u'airflow-spark-example', '--class', 'class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi', '--queue', u'root.default', 'path/to/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.1.jar', u'1000']. Error code is: 101.
```

**What I've done**

1. I copied [spark_submit_operator.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/incubator-airflow/master/airflow/contrib/operators/spark_submit_operator.py) into `$SPARK_HOME/plugins`
2. I edited spark_default connection:

   - `host: local`
   - `Extra: {"queue": "root.default", "deploy_mode": "cluster", "spark_home": "", "spark_binary": "spark-submit", "namespace": "default"}`

My dag:

```
from airflow import DAG

from airflow.contrib.operators.spark_submit_operator import SparkSubmitOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 7, 31)
}
dag = DAG('spark_example_new', default_args=args, schedule_interval="*/10 * * * *")

operator = SparkSubmitOperator(
    task_id='spark_submit_job',
    conn_id='spark_default',
    java_class='class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi',
    application='/path/to/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.1.jar',
    total_executor_cores='1',
    executor_cores='1',
    executor_memory='2g',
    num_executors='1',
    name='airflow-spark-example',
    verbose=False,
    driver_memory='1g',
    application_args=["1000"],
    conf={'master':'spark://<HOSTNAME>:7077'},
    dag=dag,
)
```

Comment: I checked the log, it failed because of `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo:

`java_class='class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi'`

it should be  `java_class='org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi'`